# Unable to turn ON python extension in azure data explorer cluster

Tags: plugins, azure-data-explorer, kql, kusto-explorer

I want to work with python plugins in Kusto. For that we need to enable the python language extension in cluster as mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/language-extensions?WT.mc_id=Portal-Microsoft_Azure_Kusto)
But whenever I try to do so, the Save button kind of freezes. When I open the configurations tab under settings, and select "On" for python extension (or R extension), the save button becomes gray and unclickable.
[image]
Is this a fault in the portal or is there some mistake that I am making  or is it that there is something else I must enable/disable in cluster for sandboxes to work?

Specifications of cluster:

Region-East Asia,
Instance Count-2,
Compute specification- Standard_E16as_v4+3TB_PS (chosen in accordance with this [VM list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/concepts/sandboxes#virtual-machine-sizes)),
Engine Type-v3,

Encryption:

Double Encryption-Off,
Disk Encryption -Off,
Define tenants permissions-Specify tenants,
Scale out- Optimized autoscale (minimum instance count 2 and maxmimum instance count 5)

Please tell me if there is something wrong with my cluster specifications. How can I enable sandbox in my ADX cluster?

Comment: these types of issues are best addressed by opening a support ticket - you can do so from the portal at the bottom of the left pane, under "Support + troubleshooting -> New support request"

Comment: Is there any reason this is happening?
Can you once confirm if the same is happening on your cluster? Since I might be making some mistake while setting cluster specifications.

Comment: I have generated the ticket as said

Comment: This was a bug, which is resolved now. Thanks